# Is it possible to lock the ASP.net Dataset

Tags: asp.net, dataset

I am having one requirement for locking the entire dataset. Is it possible to lock the ASP.net dataset that no further updates to dataset to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but you could always call the `DataSet.RejectChanges` Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.rejectchanges.aspx